# UITableViewCell Identifier without ARC floods memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on an old project that runs without ARC. It has a lot of bugs and the code looks ugly and i'm rewriting it.

Take a quick look at my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell = [self createCellWithInfo:[self.search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)createCellWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@“Cell”] autorelease];
    //set image for cell
    //set text for cell.textlabel
    //set text for cell.detailTextLabel
    //create an UIButton and add to cell.content view
    return cell;
}
```

the point is at this line of code
`[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@“Cell”] autorelease]`

if I use `@"Cell"` here, then the memory will rise up when I'm scrolling up and down continously on the table.
After about 15 seconds of scrolling, my iphone 5c becomes lag.

if I set it to `nil`, everything is fine.

Can anybody explain this please ? I'm not familliar with non-ARC.

Thanks.

Comment: A good practice in Objective C to evaluate is something is nil is: `if (!cell)` instead of `if (cell == nil)`

Comment: Unless there's a good reason why not click "Edit -> Convert to Obj-C ARC" ?

Comment: I agree with @MikePollard, I bet this app is leaking more than Edward Snowden.

Comment: lol, that's a really vivid comparison. Back to the topic, I would if I could convert it to ARC but it contains some old addition classes that doesn't support ARC, like `ASIHTTPRequest`. I added `-fnc -objc -arc` but some other errors appear and I'm working on it. Meanwhile, the project still has to move forward, you know...

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `if` block you are creating the cell without calling autorelease, which leaks memory without ARC.

And after the `if` block you are recreating it anyway (whether or not it was recycled), with autorelease this time, where all you should really be doing is reset its relevant properties so that you can successfully reuse a recycled cell (or configure a new cell).

Try replacing your code as follows:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [self updateCell:cell withInfo:[self.search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

-(void)updateCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image for cell
    //set text for cell.textlabel
    //set text for cell.detailTextLabel
    //create an UIButton and add to cell.content view
}
```

Comment: Just an aside, the reason you need `autorelease` is because every `init*` must be paired with a release, but since you can't release the cell after you return it, you defer the release with a call to `autorelease`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

alone takes care of cell initialisation, you don't need the other line.

Comment: .. but it should probably have an autorelease anyway.

Comment: @JamesWebster true. It's been a long time since I non-ARC'd! :)